# Recalculate and redistribute prorated percentage (using M&Ms as an example)

Tags: javascript, algorithm, finance

Given an original distribution of items, using a percentage "share", is there a formula available to redistribute items on a prorated basis when one of the items is removed, based on the percentage share of the remaining items?

Using a bag of 1000 M&Ms that you hand picked at the M&Ms store as an example...

**Original distribution**

15% red

30% green

20% brown

15% orange

20% yellow

Someone comes along and complains that the their favorite color M&M, orange, are all out. Since you're largely indifferent to orange, you offer up yours in trade as long as they can be replaced with a prorated proportion of the remaining colors based on the original proportions. Because, green is your favorite M&M and you want to make sure you're getting more green than yellow and brown, and more yellow and brown than red.

I would imagine there has to be a formula that can be used to calculate the prorated redistribution after the 15% of M&Ms are removed, but for the life of me I can't find it.

Comment: What is your programming language?

Comment: @AleksAndreev - programming language is JavaScript in this case. However pseudo code is also fine since the problem is really language independent.

Comment: Please do not spam language tags, then. Only use the tags where people with that specific language expertise would be able to help you.

Comment: isn't it just `original_percentage / 0.85`?

Comment: Thank you @user3080953. I do not know why that had me so befuddled!